# current_date casting

Tags: mysql, datetime

```
string selectSql = "update " + table + " set state_" + mode + "_id=1 WHERE stoping_" + mode + " < current_date;";
```

When I call `current_date`, it returns `yyyy-MM-dd` format, but I want to return `dd.MM.yyyy` format, how can I do that. please help. My program works fine when I am trying

```
string selectSql = "update " + table + " set state_" + mode + "_id=1 WHERE stoping_" + mode + " < '16.04.2010';";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL date format is YYYY-MM-DD, but using str_to_date() and date_format() you can change the date format.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

In your case, try `DATE_FORMAT(current_date, '%d.%M.%Y')`

Comment: this example won't work though. DATE_FORMAT('2010-04-16', '%d.%M.%Y') would

Comment: I just pasted here date in his example, I could write just <current_date>, that's not the point.

Comment: That's huge SO problem: everyone "just paste", not even trying to think. One don't need DATE_FORMAT for the current date. As it would be senseless to use formatted date in comparison statements.

Comment: It's just your problem. You think, he writes in his code '2010-04-16' or '16.04.2020' ? He just needed to know how to convert the date to 'dd.MM.yyyy' and nothing more, I gave him the answer how to do that, so you think you gave him that answer he wanted?

Comment: And why did it work in for him, if you say, that it doesn't work? It means, he got what he wanted. 
The End.

Answer (score 1):

mysql has a function that return current date - `curdate()`

So, your query must be like

```
update table set state_mode_id=1 WHERE stoping_mode < curdate()
```

But you have 2 major faults (or even 3):

1. date field must have a format of YYYY-MM-DD, not anything else
2. such an update is senseless at all, because all such states being *evaluated* at select time
3. assembling table name at query time is a sign of very bad database design

Answer (score 0):

YYYY-MM-DD is mySQL's native date format. I find it hard to believe that doing a comparison against a DD-MM-YYYY string works?

Anway, what you are looking for is [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: tring selectSql = "update " + table + " set state_" + mode + "_id=1 WHERE stoping_" + mode + " < '16.04.2010';";

works fine!!!!, but i need to give current_date

Answer (score 0):

Use any function like this to return your format

```
function ChangeDateforShow($inputdate) {
  if($inputdate>0) {
    $date  = substr($inputdate,8,2);
    $month = substr($inputdate,5,2);
    $year  = substr($inputdate,0,4);
    $show = $date.".".$month.".".$year;
    return $show;
  }
}
```

Comment: no it doesnt works in SQL select command, when i am passing string, for example customDate, which is equal "16.04.2010", it's not working

string selectSql = "update " + table + " set state_" + mode + "_id=1 WHERE stoping_" + mode + " < 'customDATE';";

Comment: function ChangeDateforDB($inputdate) {
  if($inputdate>0) {
    $date  = substr($inputdate,0,2);
    $month = substr($inputdate,3,2);
    $year  = substr($inputdate,6,4);
    $show = $year."-".$month."-".$date;
    return $show;
  }
}

Ok use this function in db itself like

selectSql = "update " + table + " set state_" + mode + "_id=1 WHERE stoping_" + mode + " < 'ChangeDateforDB(customDATE)';"

Or otherwise you will move for mysql date_format() only

Answer (score 0):

```
function ChangeDateforDB($inputdate) {
  if($inputdate>0) {
    $date  = substr($inputdate,0,2);
    $month = substr($inputdate,3,2);
    $year  = substr($inputdate,6,4);
    $show = $year."-".$month."-".$date;
    return $show;
  }
}
```

Ok use this function in db itself like

```
selectSql = "update " + table + " set state_" + mode + "_id=1 WHERE stoping_" + mode + " < 'ChangeDateforDB(customDATE)';"
```

Or otherwise you will move for mysql date_format() only